# Title too long separated in two lines

Tags: sectioning, chapters, frame-title

I have a long sentence in my chapter title, which I separated into two lines like this (I reduced the extra space between the two lines).

```
\chapter{Rare Earth doped materials \\ [-1.5ex] for temperature 
sensing }
```

The problem now is that the title is split into two lines in the running head also, and it doesn't look nice. Any idea about how to fix it? Thx!
 [image]

Comment: Welcome ... can you provide a MWE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't provide a `MWE`, hence assume that the below tag may help you...

```
\chapter[Short title]{full title}
```

If not so, please provide a `MWE`

Comment: It worked!! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Vanessa Glad to hear that the suggestion helps you...Please accept the answer is useful by click the tick mark....Thanks...